# Logstash data filter for column with multiplevalues to array type

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat, elk

I have a csv column hotspots, which contains multiple values with comma seprated
NAME,HOTSPOTS
"abc","spot1,spot2"
"xyz","spot2,spot3"

In logstash filter
i tried
**case1:**  is giving error

```
split {
  field => "HOTSPOTS"
  separator => ","
  target => "hotspot_array"
}
```

**case2:** is sending as text field in elk

```
mutate {
    split => { "HOTSPOTS" => "," }
    add_field => { "hotspot_array" => "%{[HOTSPOTS]}" }
  }
```

How to push hotspots to elk in array format through logstash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```rb
filter{
    csv {
        separator => ","
        columns => ["NAME", "HOTSPOTS"]
    }
    
    mutate {
        copy => { "HOTSPOTS" => "hotspot_array" }
    }
    mutate {
        split => {
            "hotspot_array" => ","
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is going elastic search as text type object, I am  looking  for nested object

Comment: You have to define the mapping before hand then. AND update the question as it is not clear ;)